# md-warn switch for Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, uiswitch

This codepen is a demo of Angular Material switch.

http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/rxNxXo

What is the difference between a switch with md-warn and one without?

```
<md-switch ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
    Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-model="data.cb2" aria-label="Switch 2" ng-true-value="'yup'" ng-false-value="'nope'" class="md-warn">
    Switch 2 (md-warn): {{ data.cb2 }}
  </md-switch>
```

I am not able to see the difference in the demo. From the documentation https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSwitch, I cannot get more information on md-warn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with "color intentions" wich are explained under the Theming section on the Angular Material site: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/01_introduction

Valid color intentions in Angular Material include:

- primary - used to represent primary interface elements for a user
- accent - used to represent secondary interface elements for a user
- warn - used to represent interface elements that the user should be
  careful of

Each one of these intentions is applied by means of a class wich is, as usual, its name preceded by "md-", that is, "md-warn", "md-accent" and "md-primary".

The color that each of these classes applies will vary depending on the theme and/or color paletted that you've defined for your application.

By default md-warn will turn your switch orange (actually rgb(255, 87,34)) when applied. You don't see much difference because it's quite similar to the default color wich is some sort of pink/magenta if you didn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

on the second button : `class="md-warn"`

md-warn is just a styling css class in ng-material causing the button to be of a different color when active.

In the demo the color is changing from pink to orange.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `md-warn` is a CSS class for angular material. It shows the content in `#FC0366` color.